# Cómo reproducir y pausar audio dentro de un Iframe

Tags: javascript, html5, iframe, audio

Cómo reproducir  con un botón  y otro botón para detener un audio que está dentro de un `<iframe>` en HTML5.

Intente esto pero nada

```
function silenciar() {
    var x = document.getElementById("iframe");
    var y = x.contentWindow;
    y.document.getElementById("audio").muted = true;
}
```

Comment: El iframe tiene `id="iframe"` ?

Comment: no, lo puse a manera de ejemplo

Comment: @ShwanNicolasSerranoAriza No funciona? ¿ Muestra algún error? , recuerde que el contenido del iframe y de la página donde se inserta y desea manipular deben estar en el mismo servidor.

Answer (score 3):

Primero deberemos crear los botones en HTML:

```
<button onclick="playAudio()" type="button">Reproducir</button>
<button onclick="pauseAudio()" type="button">Pausar</button>
```

Después, en JavaScript deberemos obtener el elemento **audio** dentro del **iframe** correspondiente y definir las funciones para reproducir y pausar:

```
var iframe = document.getElementById("iframe");
var iframeDoc = iframe.contentDocument || iframe.contentWindow.document;
var audio = iframeDoc.getElementById("audio");

function playAudio() { 
    audio.play(); 
} 

function pauseAudio() { 
    audio.pause(); 
}
```

Puedes echarle un ojo a documentación relacionada con tu pregunta:

> Cómo obtener elementos dentro de un iframe en este [enlace](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_frame_contentdocument.asp) y cómo gestionar un elemento de audio en este [otro](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_audio_pause.asp).

Recuerda, como te comenta Dev. Joel, que el iframe debe estar bajo el mismo dominio, si no no podrás acceder a su contenido interno ([Cross-site scripting](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting)). Espero haberte ayudado a solucionar tu problema.